# Prove that (a;b) is uncountable, where a;b are real numbers and a < b

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I can assume (0,1) is uncountable. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Hint: find a bijection $(a,b) \to (0,1)$. It can be a simple, linear function.

Comment: This space isn't really for homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, find a bijection, how does 
$$f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$
Work for you?